# Change text of an element from options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the text of a element by clicking on another button. So if I click on a button with text the desired element will get the same text.

This is for a fan-made game menu for Halo 5 Guardians - PC version. 
It will be tool for players to use to their advantage.

```
<div class="left_menu" id=left_menu>
  <button id="option1" class="left_menu-option">option 1</button>
  <button id="option2" class="left_menu-option">option 2</button>
  <button id="option3" class="left_menu-option">option 3</button>
</div>

<div>
<button class="left_menu-open" id="left_menu_open">
  <span class="button-text">text goes here</span>
</button>
</div>
```

I've tried using dropdowns and select menus, but the main requirement is that the button needing text changed can be in a separate div from the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `.text()` function, this lets you set the text of the `span` within your button. It will also let you get the text from the clicked button.

> N.B. you're naming convention was a little odd so I've changed `.left_menu-option` to `.left_menu_option` so that it is consistent with the convention you've used for the button (`#left_menu_open`).

---

## Demo

```js
// Add click event to all buttons with the class .left_menu-option
$(".left_menu_option").click( function() {

  // Set the text of the button
  $("#left_menu_open .button-text").text($(this).text());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left_menu" id=left_menu>
  <button id="option1" class="left_menu_option">option 1</button>
  <button id="option2" class="left_menu_option">option 2</button>
  <button id="option3" class="left_menu_option">option 3</button>
</div>

<div>
<button class="left_menu-open" id="left_menu_open">
  <span class="button-text">text goes here</span>
</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events). [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/) makes it easy (since you tagged jQuery).

```js
$(document).on('click', '#left_menu button', function(){
  $("#left_menu_open .button-text").text(this.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left_menu" id=left_menu>
  <button id="option1" class="left_menu-option">option 1</button>
  <button id="option2" class="left_menu-option">option 2</button>
  <button id="option3" class="left_menu-option">option 3</button>
</div>

<div>
<button class="left_menu-open" id="left_menu_open">
  <span class="button-text">text goes here</span>
</button>
</div>
```